# How to extract last modified date of bucket S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to extract the last modification of the bucket object:

[image]

Currently my code returns me in list with this format:

[image]

How can I get it to return in a similar format:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

1. store comma seperated values in a single variable say `time_string=2021,3,23,19,43,18`.
2. `pub_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string,'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`.
3. `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` you can formate it any format as you like.
4. Referce for python doc for these values https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

example code

```
string="2013-1-25"
datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
prints "01/25/13"
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have some code calling `list_objects()`.

If so, the `LastModified` field is already stored as a `datetime`. You can manipulate it however you want.

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='BUCKETNAME')

for object in response['Contents']:

    # 2021-02-08 04:00:28+00:00
    print(object['LastModified'])

    # 2021-02-08 04:00:28
    print(object['LastModified'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me with the .strftime function ('% Y-% m-% d% H:% M:% S'). Now I am looking to solve this:

Comment: ['7144/202103231443/', '2021-03-23 19:43:18']
['7144/202103231500/', '2021-03-23 19:43:38']
['7144/202103231621/', '2021-03-23 19:43:54']
['7100/202103222047/', '2021-03-23 01:47:30']
['7100/202103222050/', '2021-03-23 01:48:07']
['7100/202103222100/', '2021-03-23 01:48:31']

Comment: 7144 is an AWS bucket with their  sub buckets. I have to get the most current sub bucket by date. Same for 7100.

Comment: Are you asking a new question? If so, please create a new Question. But, please search for it first, because it sounds like a common thing people ask.