# change date format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format using python

Tags: python

I am new to python and  trying to import data from csv file to mysql table. the only issue is all data  except datetime is not importing . I am getting all nulls in the datefield , I dont know where i am going wrong.

```
for row in reader:
    print row
    try:
        (location_id, vrm, start_datetime,end_datetime,ticket_price,crap) = [x.decode('utf-8-sig') for x in row]
    except:
        print "Error with row: " % row
        #sys.exit(3)

    tmp = start_datetime.split(" ")
    start_date = tmp[0]
    start_time = tmp[1]

    tmp = end_datetime.split(" ")
    end_date = tmp[0]
    end_time = tmp[1]

    vrm = vrm.replace(' ', '')
    vrm = vrm.upper()

    tmp = start_date.split('/')
    tmp = end_date.split('/')

    SessionCost = float(ticket_price)/ 100

    iso_date = "%s-%s-%s" %(tmp[0],tmp[1],tmp[2])
    entryDatetime = "%s " % iso_date
    expiryDatetime = "%s " % iso_date
    sql_local = """INSERT INTO customer_1.pay_and_display
        (plate, machine_id, ticket_datetime, expiry_datetime, ticket_name, ticket_price)
        VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s") """ % (vrm, location_id, start_datetime, 
        end_datetime, "IPSWL",SessionCost)
    print sql_local
    cursor.execute(sql_local)
```

Comment: You can use strptime to get a datetime object from text... https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime Then accessing the individual components out of that is trivial.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66792148/13126651 check this answer, this will guide you a way on how to process :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `strptime`

```py
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("01/23/2021 04:12:56 AM", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')

print(dt) #2021-01-23 04:12:56
```

If your date is using a 12 hour clock, change `%H` to `%I`

Also note that `dt` in this example is a date object. Printing it calls it's `__str__` (or maybe `__repr__`) method. To use it in your SQL you will probably have to do this `str(dt)`.

[Here](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime) is a link to information on the various format characters and their meaning.

Comment: I tried the above  but received -----ValueError: time data 'start_datetime' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' ( the datetime on csv file is  8/19/2020 4:31:47 AM)

Comment: @preethi It's using the exact format that you posted in your title. If the date format you are using is different than what you claimed, then you will need to adjust the format portion of `strptime` to match it. Read the docs for `strptime`, especially the part that describes the format characters. It seems that neither your month or hour are zero padded . That's not what your title describes. I added in the format for `AM/PM` though, as I missed that initially.

Answer (score 0):

If a program I'm working on uses date or time I like to copy and paste this simple block of code. The 'time' variable is a [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) for the present moment, the 'dtRn' variable makes it easy to display a single string containing datetime. [Link to W3Schools Python Datetime Options](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp)

```
import datetime
from time import strftime, strptime

time = datetime.datetime.now()
dtRn = str(strftime("%x") + " " + strftime("%X"))
```

If you're interested in how long it takes to run a program (start to finish); add a variant of this block of code to the end of the script, and subtract the end time from the start time.